# Are there any known Pre-Shmi Skywalkers?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

It’s a common complaint to say that Star Wars as a franchise is all about a single family, but as far as I am aware the Skywalker family “starts” with Shmi Skywalker, who has no known siblings or parents.

I know that the Skywalkers being unknown is important symbolism, but are there any even background mentions of characters named Skywalker from earlier time periods? (Canon or Legends)

Comment: Definitely a dupe. If a new pre-Shmi Skywalker had been revealed, I would have updated my answer

Comment: We know that she had parents, but that's it. We don't know their names or anything about them.

Comment: @Valorum For any other character, “no known parents” should have implied what I meant (“we don’t know her parents”). In this family I guess there’s another (wrong) implication I can’t deny.

Comment: https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=X3UgEAAAQBAJ&pg=PT12&lpg=PT12&dq=%22In+her+own+youth,+Shmi+had+once+known+freedom,+but+that+was+before+she+and+her+parents+were+captured+by+a+roving+band+of+pirates%22&source=bl&ots=iYJ-bqQcbU&sig=ACfU3U1FAyCREmf4KbBxV408swYDluyL_w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi38P347-r_AhXEgv0HHUf5DPMQ6AF6BAgNEAI#v=onepage&q=%22In%20her%20own%20youth%2C%20Shmi%20had%20once%20known%20freedom%2C%20but%20that%20was%20before%20she%20and%20her%20parents%20were%20captured%20by%20a%20roving%20band%20of%20pirates%22&f=false - We don't know their fates either